# How to rotate h264 video?

Tags: video, codecs, avconv, h264

I've tried the following:

```
$ avconv -i in.mov -codec:video copy -codec:audio copy -filter transpose=clock out.mov
avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 30 2013 22:23:21 with gcc 4.7.2
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    creation_time   : 2013-03-03 15:47:47
  Duration: 00:00:18.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 45882 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuvj420p, 1920x1080, 44343 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-03 15:47:47
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-03 15:47:47
Output #0, mov, to 'out.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    creation_time   : 2013-03-03 15:47:47
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: avc1 / 0x31637661, yuvj420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 44343 kb/s, 24k tbn, 24k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-03 15:47:47
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-03 15:47:47
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=  455 fps=379 q=-1.0 Lsize=  106291kB time=18.94 bitrate=45983.9kbits/s    
video:102724kB audio:3558kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.008270%
```

The resulting out.mov plays just fine, but the video is not rotated. I've tried many different filters:

```
transpose=1
rotate=1
rotate=clock
```

All with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was necessary to install the `x264` package, and use `-codec:video libx264` rather than `copy` to make this work. Strangely, nothing in the output indicated missing codecs or conflicting options. The working commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install x264
$ avconv -i in.mov -codec:video libx264 -codec:audio copy -vf transpose=clock out.mov
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI, the accepted answer using libx264 is not entirely complete, at least on 12.04.4.  You have to install another package (and all its dependencies) to get the encoder library libx264 hooked into avconv.

See [this post on ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2005629%5D)

```
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

Then you can verify it's installed:

`$ avconv -codecs|grep 264
avconv version 0.8.10-4:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 20:56:59 with gcc 4.6.3
 D V D  h264            H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
 D V D  h264_vdpau      H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (VDPAU acceleration)
  EV    libx264         libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10`

Comment: Too late to verify this now (I had probably installed it already when running into this problem), but +1 for a plausible extra dependency.